# Dialogflow webhook fulfillment not returning response

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I am building a chatbot, and i want to do some validation on address (zipcodes in the netherlands have to be written like [1234XX]. But after my intent and the webhook is being called nothing is being returned to the conversation. It just says "empty response"

In Firebase the following error comes up:

```
Error: No handler for requested intent
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:287:29)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:49:9)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:689:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:673:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

The code i am running is the following:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function woningwaarde_instant_function (agent) {
    // get the employee ID parameter from the request header received from Dialogflow
    let zipcode = agent.parameters.zipcode;
    if (zipcode.length === 6) { 
        agent.add(`The length of the Employee ID should be six characters. Please enter the correct ID.`); 
    } else { agent.add('lengte van postcode == 6'); }
  }

  function welcome (agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
    agent.add(agent.request_.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText);
  }

  function fallback (agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('woningwaarde_instant', woningwaarde_instant_function);
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

It seems like
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
Doesn't satisfy but i have no clue how to fix this and i have been trying everything i could find online all day long...

[image]

Comment: Can you show the Dialogflow test area? What is the identified intent showing there?

Comment: I edited the original post, but as you can see it shows the woningwaarde_instant as identified intent.

Comment: Were you able to access the functions of the Default welcome intent and fallback intent

Comment: Yes if i access the Default Fallback Intent it returns the two strings defined here:
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);

Comment: When you make the call that gives the error, what is the JSON displayed by the `console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));` line? (can you update the question with this). If you change the name of the Intent to something shorter (such as "i1") and change this in the webhook as well, do you still get the error?

Comment: What dependencies are in your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I think your welcome function handler has an underscore where there shouldn't be one and instead it should be:

```
    agent.add(request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText);
```